# simple mysql query works in phpmyadmin but will not work in a php script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been working all day on a php script that pulls data from a single mysql database. My script has worked fine, and then all of a sudden mysql stopped returning rows with certain queries. It started with a complex join, but now one certain query will not return a row. The same exact query pasted into phpmyadmin does return a row.

First, the query:

```
    $sql = "SELECT tagsetsname_id FROM tagsets_docpaths_sets WHERE documents_paths_id = '233'";  //the '233' comes from {$_SESSION['document']['docpathid']}
```

When I paste this query in phpmyadmin I get this result:

```
tagsetsname_id
    0
```

That is the result I wanted. The tagsetsname_id is 0.

When I try this in a php script:

```
    //$db is connection to a database, some queries are working so $db is connected
    $sql = "SELECT tagsetsname_id FROM tagsets_docpaths_sets 
    WHERE documents_paths_id = '233'";
$res = $db->query($sql);
```

And then look at $res in Firebug, I have the following result:

```
    mysqli_result(
    current_field =
    field_count =
    lengths =
    num_rows =
    type =
    )
```

It's empty. I'm baffled.

I restarted apache; I restarted mysql.

What simple thing could I be missing?

Am new to mysql. Could the database be corrupt in some way? Is there a rebuild or something I could try?

**script

```
    $sql = "SELECT tagsetsname_id FROM tagsets_docpaths_sets \
    WHERE documents_paths_id = '{$_SESSION['document']['docpathid']}'";
    //{$_SESSION['document']['docpathid']} = 233;

    $res = $db->query($sql);
    $row = $res->fetch_row();
    $firephp->trace($db);
    $firephp->group('tags');
    $firephp->log('$sql');
    $firephp->trace($sql);
    $firephp->log('$row');
    $firephp->trace($row);
    $firephp->groupEnd();
```

**debug

```
    mysqli(
    affected_rows =
    client_info =
    client_version =
    connect_errno =
    connect_error =
    errno =
    error =
    field_count =
    host_info =
    info =
    insert_id =
    server_info =
    server_version =
    stat =
    sqlstate =
    protocol_version =
    thread_id =
    warning_count =
    )

    SELECT tagsetsname_id FROM tagsets_docpaths_sets WHERE documents_paths_id = '233' 

     $row
    null
    File         Line   Instruction
    .../create_metatags.php

    291

    FirePHP->trace( '')
```

YET in phpmyadmin the pasted $sql from the debug works perfectly. Am I crazy?!

Comment: You need to `fetch_assoc()` from the query result. Otherwise, you only have a result resource. As in `$row = $res->fetch_assoc(); print_r($row);`

Comment: $row
null
File Line Instruction
.../create_metatags.php
 
233
 
FirePHP->trace( '')

Comment: If after properly fetching, `$row` is null, then indeed you got no rows back. Make sure you are connected to the right database! I assume you are connected to something, otherwise your original inspection of `$res` would have been null rather than a `mysqli_result` object...

Comment: The other queries using the exact same established connection $db work. I am only working with one database.

Comment: Is \ in the $sql actually there in the code or just added here for presentation? Try removing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown on this page https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php ,  $res->fetch_row() returns results in an array with numeric indexes.  Your result should be in $row[0].

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `'` in `'233'` I believe.

Comment: It doesn't matter for a numeric value. You can quote it or unquote it.

Comment: Tried it with and without the ''. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

What is the object type of $db...? You might need to fetch results from $res

i.e. $data = $res->fetchAll();

Comment: Am using mysqli. I tried a fetch_row. null was the result. All my other queries are working. I am simply stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks very obvious, first you didn't use the exact syntax when pass numeric data to be equal to some filed. second you are not fetching any thing from the database, even not execute, even not prepare to be executed. it is correct you must not see any thing on the screen...try to follow the following...

```
<pre>
$sql = "SELECT tagsetsname_id FROM tagsets_docpaths_sets 
    WHERE documents_paths_id = 233 ";  // with out (').
$res = $db->query($sql);
</pre>
```

then add the following after you query the sql...

```
<pre>
$query = $db->prepare($sql);      
$query->execute();
$ent = $query->fetchAll();
</pre>
```

In general use this...

```
<pre>
 $sql = "SELECT tagsetsname_id FROM tagsets_docpaths_sets 
        WHERE documents_paths_id = 233 ";  // with out (').
 $query = $db->prepare($sql);      
 $query->execute();
 $ent = $query->fetchAll();
</pre>
```

then print_r($ent);
now you should get list of available data as array.

is that helpful?